# Number of ways to write a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ as a sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

My intuition, from checking many cases, is that there is only ONE way to write a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ as a sum of two squares. But how can I formally show this?

Comment: For a proof, see $3.)$ [here](http://f2.org/maths/nthproof.html#rootneg1).

Comment: The question was already at MSE here: [If $p\equiv1\mod{4}$, then $p=a^{2}+b^{2}$ where a and b are uniquely determined](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112313/if-p-equiv1-mod4-then-p-a2b2-where-a-and-b-are-uniquely-determined)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am unclear as to how $(ad)^2 - (bc)^2$ follows from $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$.  This seems to be a common theme in proofs not involving this Euclidean Domain.