# How can I find the number of integral Pythagorean triples with a given hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry

How can I find the number of integral pythagorean triples if the hypotenuse is $2^{4035}$? I want to do this without finding them all and counting them.

Comment: Your question is related to the special case of this one : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928753/find-the-cardinality-of-the-following-set-s-n-x-yx2y2-n-textwhere-x .

Comment: Let $n$ be a positive integer, we want to count the pythagorean triangles with hypotenuse $=\sqrt{n}$ ; then if $n$ is not square this amount is equal to $ \dfrac{r_2(n)}{8}  =  \dfrac{d_{(4,1)}(n)-d_{(4,3)}(n)}{2} $; where by $d_{(4,i)}(n)$ we meant the number of positive divisors of $n$ which is congruent to $i$ modue $4$ and if $n$ is square this amount is equal to $ \dfrac{r_2(n)-4}{8}  =  \dfrac{d_{(4,1)}(n)-d_{(4,3)}(n)-1}{2} $. In a very special case when hypotenuse $=2^{4035}$; then we have only one triangle as follows $(2^{2032},2^{2032};2^{4035})$.

Comment: @accursed, $(2^{2032})^2+(2^{2032})^2\neq (2^{4035})^2$.

Comment: @Ennar, yes you are right; it should replaced by $\sqrt{2^{4035}}$.

Comment: @accursed, which is not an integer, unfortunately. If I'm not being stupid, there shouldn't be any Pythagorean triples with given hypotenuse except trivial ones with one leg $0$.

Comment: @Ennar , no my dear Ennar, on contrary; you are right and I am mistaken, there is none in that case.